# Reading txt file (similar to dictionary format) into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, formatting

I have a txt file that looks like this:

```
('GTCC', 'ACTB'): 1
('GTCC', 'GAPDH'): 2
('CGAG', 'ACTB'): 1
('CGAG', 'GAPDH'): 4
```

where the first string is a gRNA name, the second string is a gene name, and the number is a count of those two strings occurring together.

I want to read this into a pandas dataframe and re-shape it so that it looks like this:

```
      ACTB GAPDH
GTCC   1     2
CGAG   1     4
```

How might I do this?

The file will not always be this size-- it will often be much larger (200 gRNA names x 20 gene names) but the size will be variable. There will always only be one gRNA name and one gene name per count. The titles of the columns/rows are accurate as to what the real file will look like (some string of letters for the rows and some gene name for the columns).

Comment: Why don't you use a .json file instead?

Comment: What does that mean? I'm sorry, I'm very unfamiliar with coding.

Comment: a JSON file is a file storing datas in JavaScript Object Notation. It's used for small datasets by those ones who can't use a database instead. https://json.org

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly not the cleanest way to do it, but I figured out a way to get what I wanted:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.txt', sep=",|:", engine ='python', names=['gRNA','gene','count'])
df["gRNA"]=df["gRNA"].str.replace("(","")
df["gRNA"]=df["gRNA"].str.replace("'","")
df["gene"]=df["gene"].str.replace(")","")
df["gene"]=df["gene"].str.replace("'","")
df=df.pivot(index='gRNA', columns='gene', values='count')
```